# phpstorm can not commit timeout / PROPFIND request failed

Tags: php, svn, phpstorm, commit

I am using **PhpStorm** and I can not commit files, but I can update from the SVN and browse the SVN repository.

I get

```
PROPFIND request failed on 'svn_address'
```

Seems like a timeout issue. I can commit from Eclipse without problem, so this is PhpStorm issue.

Comment: Have you tried to delete your local copy, complete checkout, change a file and comit? Sometimes the SVN plugin needs much love. Did you set up the right Version of SVN in PhpStorm accroding to the server Version?

Comment: Maybe this is interesseting: http://codebetter.com/darrellnorton/2005/11/07/propfind-request-failed-when-connecting-to-subversion-using-self-issued-server-certificates/

Comment: Tried new checkout and clean up, not helping. going to use tortoise svn. very disappointing...

Comment: try increasing timeout - Settings | Version Control | Subversion | Network. And check your proxy settings